# Not So Much A Question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A Thanksgiving Thank You](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31071/a-thanksgiving-thank-you)

I am not sure exactly where to post this, but I have found solutions to many questions that I have googled directing me to StackOverflow.

I recently started exploring the site and participating and am extremely impressed with the whole site and its functionality.

Just wanted to say kudos, this site is excellent and I look forward to participating in both assisting others and finding assistance myself.

Excellent work to th developers and participants of this site.

Comment: @YOU: That's either really harsh or really funny, I can't decide.

Comment: Customers who liked StackOverflow also liked [these sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites?sort=users).

Comment: @Madmartigan I don't understand your response

Comment: Excellent, glad to have you on board! And as Reg said, check out.. http://stackexchange.com/sites as well